# UnauthorizedAccessException trying to delete a file in a folder where I can delete others files with the same code

Tags: c#, exception, io

I'm getting a Unauthorized Access Exception

- in a file which I can delete manually.
- in a folder where I'm able to delete by code other files
- and the file isn't marked as read only
- besides, I'm using Windows XP in a standalone PC and I have not assigned any permissions to the folder or the file.
- no other process is using the file

If it helps, this is the code where the exception ocurrs:

```
protected void DeleteImage(string imageName)
{
    if (imageName != null)
    {
        string f = String.Format("~/Images/{0}", imageName);
        f = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(f);
        if (File.Exists(f))
        {
            if (f != null) File.Delete(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Why could this happen?

Comment: This feels like a permissions issue. Are the permissions somehow different on the files that you can delete versus the one you can't?

Answer (score 38):

I encountered the same problem, and found that writing my own Directory.Delete wrapper fixed it up. This is recursive by default:

```
using System.IO;

public void DeleteDirectory(string targetDir)
{
    File.SetAttributes(targetDir, FileAttributes.Normal);

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        DeleteDirectory(dir);
    }

    Directory.Delete(targetDir, false);
}
```

Comment: What is about http://caioproiete.net/en/csharp-delete-folder-including-its-sub-folders-and-files-even-if-marked-as-read-only/ ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean? I see it's a similar function... but not exactly the same... When i used this before, it worked fine.... been awhile now though!

Comment: the `File.SetAttributes()` saved my day: i didnt notice the file i tried to delete was readonly oO'

Comment: This is the correct answer!! I had struggled for days with the error, as all it was deleting was the inner files not the folder itself. I was using libgit2sharp and trying to delete a cloned repository so I could re-clone it. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

If the directory contains a read only file, it won't delete that using Directory.Delete. It's a silly implementation by MS.

I am surprised no one suggested this method on the internet, which deletes the directory without recursing through it and changing every file's attributes. Here's that:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"rmdir /s/q C:\Test\TestDirectoryContainingReadOnlyFiles");
```

(Change a bit to not to fire a cmd window momentarily, which is available all over the internet)

Comment: I don't think it's that silly. If you 'delete' it manually, you're actually moving it to the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde depends, I usually use shift+del to delete files permanently.

Comment: This is the solution I've been looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If it's not read-only it's possible that it is currently in use by another process.

Comment: Not answer, better like comment

Comment: @Kiquenet: Why wouldn't this be an answer? It is in fact what was happening for me. Only, in fact it was the process itself that was trying to delete it. (I had accidentally referenced a project in my update script.)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the obvious first...

*When you open the file property and take a look at its security settings.  Does the user running the code (i.e. if this is ASP.NET, Network Services / Domain Service Account) has access to actually delete the file?*
If it is not, then change it and try again.

*Are you running as administrator when trying to delete this manually?*
 If you are, then that's probably why you are able to delete it manually.  Try deleting it as the account running your ASP.NET (I'm assuming it is ASP.NET since you are using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath.)

If both failed, try to see if any other process is actually currently using this file.  Good tool to find out is [SysInternal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) Process Monitor.  Filter it by path containing your filename and you should see if anything is using it.  Terminate the process and try again.

Comment: +1 for the sysinternal tool (until now, I didn't know how to use any of the the sysinternal tools)

Comment: Trying to delete a file in use throws an UnauthorizedAccessException? I would expect another type of exception as it is not a problem with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the Same Problem but eventually came up with a Generic Approach. Below are my codes.

```
String pathfile =  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Filepath.txt" ;

if (!Directory.Exists(pathfile))
{
    File.SetAttributes(pathfile, FileAttributes.Normal);
    File.Delete(pathfile);
}


using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pathfile))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("What Ever Your Text is");
                                  
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    File.SetAttributes(pathfile, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You, the human user,  have a login with certain rights.  The Web server might have a different login with different rights. A user starting with IUSR_XXXX or some such thing.  Make sure that user has rights to the directory.

Without more info on the context in which you are deleting the file, I assume that the Web server user has different rights to a file than you do.